# Safe way of extending xfs partition

Tags: partition, xfs

I created an xfs partition using fdisk and mkfs.xfs on my 6T hhd. I ended up with only 2T. What is the safest way of expanding the partition to take up all the remaining space without disturbing the files already in the drive? Will xfs_growfs do the job? What other things should I take into consideration?

Comment: Was your disk was partitioned with GPT? MBR has an inherent limitation of about 2 TB.

Comment: I used fdisk to create the partition.

Comment: To verify this, can you run `fdisk -l [disk]` and update the question with its output?

Comment: Don't have access to the machine right now but I distinctly remember getting a size of 2T on /dev/sdg1 but fdisk correctly detects that the whole device (/dev/sdg) is around 6T.

Comment: convert to gpt, grow partition, grow xfs

Comment: After doing some tests, I've found that the newer versions of `fdisk` can support GPT if you tell it to. Unfortunately, the default is still MBR. You can attempt to convert this using `gdisk`, but that is a potentially destructive operation.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways to resolve your case:
 If you can backup files to external storage:

1. destroy the filesystem
2. create dedicated volume group
3. create entire disk `/dev/sdg` as PV: `pvcreate /dev/sdg`
4. add PV to the VG
5. create LV
6. create filesystem on LV
7. restore the files

   If you do not have place to backup the files (here start with step 1, not 8, numeration in SE do not work well)
8. create two partitions `/dev/sdg2` and `/dev/sdg3` to the end of the disk
9. create VG
10. create PVs on the partitions
11. add PVs to the VG
12. create LV
13. create filesystem on this LV
14. mount this LV
15. copy files to the new filesystem
16. unmount `/dev/sdg1`
17. create on `/dev/sdg1` PV
18. add PV to VG
19. extend LV to the full size of VG